# Regexp: Keyword followed by value to extract

Tags: regex, keyword

I had this question a couple of times before, and I still couldn't find a good answer..

In my current problem, I have a console program output (string) that looks like this:

```
Number of assemblies processed = 1200
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 1197
Number of failures = 3
```

Now I want to extract those numbers and to check if there were failures. (That's a gacutil.exe output, btw.) In other words, I want to match any number [0-9]+ in the string that is preceded by 'failures = '.

How would I do that? I want to get the number **only**. Of course I can match the whole thing like /failures = [0-9]+/ .. and then trim the first characters with length("failures = ") or something like that. The point is, I don't want to do that, it's a lame workaround.

Because it's odd; if my pattern-to-match-but-not-into-output ("failures = ") comes **after** the thing i want to extract ([0-9]+), there is a way to do it:

pattern(?=expression)

To show the absurdity of this, if the whole file was processed backwards, I could use:

[0-9]+(?= = seruliaf)

... so, is there no forward-way? :T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pattern(?=expression)` is a regex positive lookahead and what you are looking for is a regex positive  lookbehind that goes like this `(?<=expression)pattern` but this feature is not supported by all flavors of regex. It depends which language you are using.

more infos at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for comparison of Lookaround feature scroll down 2/3 on this page.

Comment: cool, thanks! right, i acutally came across exactly this before but couldn't use it, i think it was in python. - luckily, this time i'm in c# and .NET .. which supports this feature. :D

Answer (score 0):

If your console output does actually look like that throughout, try splitting the string on "=" when the word "failure" is found, then get the last element (or the 2nd element). You did not say what your language is, but any decent language with string splitting capability would do the job. For example

```
gacutil.exe.... | ruby -F"=" -ane "print $F[-1] if /failure/"
```